Cannot Resolve SPEL with asperand @spring.profiles.active@ in Spring boot 3 + JUnit 5 in integration test
My ETL works flow like this
Given

SpringBoot 3.3.3
Maven 3.9.x
JDK 17
Intentionally Remove Tomcat-embedded (for specified purpose)


pom.xml

<!--No maven-surefire-plugin was set-->


application.yml

spring:
    profiles:
        active: '@spring.profiles.active@'


application-dev.yml

spring:
    main:
        web-application-type: none


DataSource.java

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    String activeProfile;
//.....

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.img.configuration")
    public DataSource imgDataSource(@Qualifier("imgDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties imgDataSourceProperties) {
        return activeProfile.equalsIgnoreCase("dev")
                ? // do dev data source initilization
                : // do other data source initialization;
    }

Then

it works with Mock Test, API call if

run it with mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev or run it in server with Environment variable spring.profile.active=dev



Issue
Now I am going to create an integration test , I set a break point in DataSource.java and check the value of String activeProfile; I found the value is always String of '@spring.profiles.active@'.
Given the server log
The
[main] INFO  [c.a.x.s.h.s.CheckEmailServiceTest:660] - The following 1 profile is active: "dev"

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
      //  , properties="spring.profiles.active=dev"
      //   when the properties was comment-out , it works , However other properties with @Value need to configured , otherwise it cannot be auto-loaded 
)
@ActiveProfiles("dev") // why it does not translate to @spring.profiles.active@ // 
@EnableAutoConfiguration // with or without it , it does not change the behavior of loading @ActiveProfiles 
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // with or without it , it does not change the behavior of loading @ActiveProfiles 
@Slf4j
class CheckEmailServiceTest {

    private CheckEmailService checkEmailServiceUnderTest;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        checkEmailServiceUnderTest = new CheckEmailService();
        

    }
}

Questions

How can I pass value to spring.profiles.active application.yml without using hard-code command line? seems @ActiveProfiles("dev") does not work (from log file, "dev" was shown, but how cannot it load / ETL to java field of DataSource.java) ?

May I use something like annotation way to run the test case ?


